# Very slow mysql request + php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

The ideia is: select all professions from a table. After this count how many professionals have the profession id in his category column. The category column store the professions id's separeted by commas (1, 2, 3, 420). The professions table has 604 rows.
I have the following piece of code:

```
<?php
$select_professions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM professions");
    if(mysql_num_rows($select_professions) == "0"){
        echo"No registers in DB";
    }else{while($row_professions = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_professions)){
        $id = $row_professions['id'];

        $count_profiles = mysql_query("SELECT 
        COUNT(FIND_IN_SET(professions.id, professional.category) > 0) AS profile_numbers
                                        FROM
                                            professions
                                        INNER JOIN
                                            professional
                                        WHERE
                                            FIND_IN_SET(professions.id,professional.category) > 0
                                        AND
                                            professions.id = $id
                                        GROUP BY
                                            professions.id");
        $reg_profiles = mysql_fetch_assoc($count_profiles);
        $numProfiles = $reg_profiles['profile_numbers'];
            if($numProfiles > 4){
                $style = 'display:none';
            }else{
                $style = '';
            }
?>
```

My basic question is WHY this is so slow in Google Chrome?
Its taking like 15 seconds to load entire page with these results in a html table. In Edge or Firefox is taking about 5 seconds. I heard about Chrome  using so much memory lately but I don't believe its soo slowly. In time this is the first time I use the FIND_IN_SET function on mysql. Is that may are slowing down the request? Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or how can be optimized? This is actualy working but we know that 15 seconds of waiting makes the user give up or think that page is not working. I have to say too that if I do the same consultation on my HeidiSQL it takes 1 second.

Comment: php is server side browser is irrelevant

Comment: create and use views and stored procedures..call them from php and get ther results . one more thing, browser has nothing to do with this. :)

Comment: FIND_IN_SET(professions.id,professional.category)

Comment: Despite the comments of php question is server side I still have the problem of opening the site by Google Chrome taking 15 seconds!
I'm even thinking that may have caught a virus but eventually as they do not hurt to ask anyone care to open the page link in the browser and see how long it takes?
http://odiarista.com.br/cadastro-lancamento.php
If the main question of comments on the server side is that by caching the request the server responds more quickly, why still takes 15 seconds on GC and takes 5 on Edge or FF to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to normalize this:

> The category column store the professions id's separeted by commas (1,
>   2, 3, 420)

This is an `n:n` relationship. Your layout:

```
professionals:
id | catgeory
12 | 1,2,4,50

professions
id | desc
1  | prof A
2  | prof B
...
```

The string operations (split the list, normalize internal, query result in to temp, ...) is very cost intensive. Better:

```
professionals:
id | ...
12 | ..


profrelations
pid | cid
12  | 1
12  | 2
12  | 4
12  | 50

professions
id | desc
1  | prof A
2  | prof B
...
```

This would skip the `COUNT(FIND_IN_SET(professions.id, professional.category) > 0)` as a string operation (even twice):

```
SELECT COUNT(cid) AS profile_numbers from professionals, profrelations where
professionals.id = profrelations.pid AND profrelations.pid = $id;
```

etc. You might restructure the above query like this, as long as you won't actually need any column from professions.

You can add a unique index on the cols `(pid, cid)` in table `profrelations` as one professional actually can have one profession only one times.

**Remark**

The different behaviour in two browser might result from the server caching the query: You're doing the query with Chrome, it's slow, but the result gets cached. Next with FF, server will respond with the cached result as its the same query again - fast. Try it three times or the other way round, should then be the same in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and code example. It's very clear and didact and I agree that is the better choice because we reduce in 2 requests like these that will be common.

Answer (score 1):

At first,
this operation `COUNT(FIND_IN_SET(professions.id, professional.category) > 0)` will not return result that you expected. `Count` in above expression will return `1` even if `find_in_set` returns `0`.
Secondly, I wouldn't use join in this case at all. This tables have no direct relation by identifiers.
I would optimize the query as following:

```
SELECT COUNT(professions.id) AS profile_numbers FROM professions, professional 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(professions.id,professional.category) > 0 AND professions.id = $id 
GROUP BY professions.id
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you by your asnwer. I used this to test and it really works and reduces the FIND_IN_SET by one and this way really don't have the problem of returning 1 if 0. Much better!